# normal distribution with random sample

Tags: probability

> The mean salary of the president of the largest 100 companies in Vermont is $ \mu = \$250,000$  with a
>   standard deviation, $ \sigma = \$20,000$. If we take a random sample of $25$ of these presidents, what is the
>   probability that their mean salary is less than $ \$240,000$?

however i got 0.00621, but the answer is 0.0019

Comment: welcome to MSE, please show your work so that we can figure out what went wrong.

Comment: the z score is -2.5 and probability 0.00621. but its wrong

Comment: So I assume that you calculated it like this:
$$
Z = \frac{240~000 - 250~000}{\left(  \frac{20~000}{\sqrt{25}} \right)} = -2.5
$$
and $\Phi(-2.5)\approx 0.0062$. The indicated correct answer would be obtained with $\Phi(-2.8943)\approx 0.0019$.

Comment: thats what... how did 0.0019 came?

Comment: Totally unrelated to the maths of the question, but the assumption that salaries are normally distributed is terrible for real life applications. Salaries are one of the prime examples of a quantity not normally distributed where assumptions to the contrary will give you predictions that are far of reality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are not adjusting for the fact that the sample is drawn without replacement from a population of only $100$ companies, and that the sample size is a substantial fraction of the population size.  That is to say, you are not using a finite population correction factor.

With $N = 100$ and $n = 25$, the finite population correction factor is $$FPC = \sqrt{\frac{N - n}{N - 1}} \approx 0.870388,$$ and the standard error of the sample mean is $$SE = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} FPC \approx 3481.55.$$  This leads to a probability of $0.0020376$.

---

From [this post in stats.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5158/explanation-of-finite-correction-factor), you can see that if the denominator of the FPC is changed to $N$ instead of $N-1$, you get an answer that is equivalent to the claimed answer of $0.0019$ within rounding error; moreover, the use of $N$ is justified as the population standard deviation $\sigma$ is known.